# Spring-boot inner jar files loading order? (embedded tomcat)

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring-boot "fat" jar (1.5.22) with embedded tomcat (tomcat-embed-core-8.5.57.jar).

Inside the jar - there are many "inner" jars under BOOT-INF/lib.

In what order are those inner jars loaded by the class-loader?

If I run `java -jar myFatSpringBoot.jar` on multiple computers - will inner jars be picked up in the **same exact** order, or does it **"depend"** on something on each computer? (FS/tmpfs/java/etc)

---

**UPDATE:** many responders indicated it takes inner jars in the exact order in which they appear in the fat jar (so at least the QA and PROD should behave same way for same fat jar, unlike it was for non-spring-boot .war apps).

Now I'm wondering if we have any machinery to preserve/enforce/specify the order of inner jars during the process of creating/packaging the jar? (maven/gradle/...)

Comment: Why is this important? Do you have race conditions between the external libraries' static initializers?

Comment: @geanakuch - there was a legacy app on older tomcat which relied on "plugins" (overriding some classes) to be loaded 1st due to alphanumeric order of WEB-INF/lib load (the paradigm broke with newer tomcats), then there was other app having accidental class-clashes due to same name in many jars - tests passed fine on QA, but failed on few of PROD hosts (because order was FS-dependent during .war-unpack), making sure we can avoid the QA-vs-PROD issue with SpringBoot, more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67710064/order-of-loading-packaging-jar-files-spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jars in `BOOT-INF/lib` are [always added to Spring Boot’s class loader in the order in which they appear in the jar](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/69b730521a47cfded60a9238016a988dee18931d/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/Launcher.java#L83-L85). This means that if you have the same class file or resource declared in multiple jars, the same one will always win across multiple runs of your application, irrespective of operating system, Java version, etc. This holds true even if you're using Spring Boot's support for [automatically unpacking certain jars](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.7/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-extract-specific-libraries-when-an-executable-jar-runs) at runtime.

Spring Boot also packages a [`BOOT-INF/classpath.idx` index file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.7/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-war-index-files-classpath) in each jar that it builds. It lists all of the nested jars "in the order that they should be added to the classpath". If you unzip the jar file such that the jars in `BOOT-INF/lib` are then ordered by the filesystem, if you continue to use Spring Boot's `JarLauncher` to launch the application [it will honour the order in the index](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.7/reference/htmlsingle/#containers-deployment).

Spring Boot contains tests, [such as these](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/69b730521a47cfded60a9238016a988dee18931d/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/bundling/BootJarIntegrationTests.java#L53-L75), that verify the ordering of the classpath, both when launching an application using `java -jar` and when using `java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`.

Comment: your word is fine, and my experience is showing same, but is there a GUARANTEE that this will hold? e.g. you're saying across Java version - but what if we move to java_corretto tomorrow and "shmorretto" next year - will paradigm hold true? e.g. is there a specific class-loader code doing/proving this (accessing jar directly and not temporary-unpacking it to FS/etc?) If the spring-boot's own classloader logic is in play here (instead of rt.jar one) - it may break with some spring flag or SprgBoot 6.0 release, right?  I value/like/respect your answer - just looking for a basis it is standing on

Comment: I've fleshed things out a bit. FWIW, I am a member of the Spring Boot team and we have no plans to stop honouring the order of the jars in `BOOT-INF/lib`. We know that the order of the classpath can be important which is why we've ensured that it is predictable and repeatable.

Comment: thank you for updating the answer with all those vital details, now I'm confident the move to springboot was the right choice. Any "best practices" to generate classpath.idx? (by maven/gradle) Or manually crafted file is a good approach?

Comment: The index file is created automatically by Spring Boot’s Maven and Gradle plugins. The ordering of the classpath is controlled by the ordering of your dependency declarations in your pom.xml or build.gradle file.

Comment: is it safe to assume that classes from `BOOT-INF/classes/` will always be loaded first from fat jar and therefore will prevail over any potentially same-FQCN classes from any nested jars from `BOOT-INF/lib/` ?

Comment: @62mkv Yes. As long as you use `JarLauncher`, `BOOT-INF/classes/` will be used before any of the jars in `BOOT-INF/lib/`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the order will remain same. It's generally the JRE related classes and then the application. You can actually see the loading order yourself.  Just launch the program with `-verbose` flag. Something like this

```
java -verbose -jar myFatSpringBoot.jar
```

This will print lots of information on what class is being loaded from which jar and which path. Apart from startup there will be few classes which will get loaded when your application is being used as generally the class-loading is lazy. You can log this info to an external file and later analyze.

```
java -verbose -jar myFatSpringBoot.jar > log.txt
```

Comment: tried it on one host and also logged strace (will try on more hosts to compare Loaded/jar order), but what worried me from strace - was: `[pid  5835] open("/myapp/myFatSpringBoot.jar", O_RDONLY) = 19
[pid  5835] open("/my.java.io.tmpdir/myFatSpringBoot.jar-spring-boot-libs-541d642d-ada7-4508-b1d5-5e1293d8f211/metrics-jersey-2.2.0.jar", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 20` , e.g. I see some of inner jars being unpacked to local FileSystem before being accessed by loader and worried of if loader may then use FS-induced order (like it used for WEB-INF/lib of non-springboot/non-embedded tomcat)